# How to capture end of line when line contains double quotes?

Tags: java, regex

I have a document where numerous lines contain double quotes like this:

```
"foo
bar
"bam"
foo "bar
```

And i want to capture the end of every line that contains a double quote.
But I don't want it to capture lines that already contain a double quote at the end.
Just the end of `"foo` and `foo "bar` should match.

I am currently stuck trying to use multiple positive lookbacks like this:
`(?<=")(?=.*)[^"]$`

Comment: You may still use `^".*[^"]$` - see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/uNpuDB/2). `replaceAll("(?m)^\".*[^\"]$", "$0\"")`. I just wonder how you are going to handle `"foo" bar`

Comment: @RadLexus That must have been a typo, I changed it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This captures the whole line. I only want it to capture the end of it since I want to append the missing double quotes.

Comment: When you say "capture the end of every line that contains a double quote" what do you mean by capture? - It seems from a comment above that you mean find lines where according to rules I define need to have a double quote added _and then add that double quote_. Is that accurate? In addition as @WiktorStribiżew mentions how would you like an example such as `"foo" bar` to be handled? Is the point to close the "quotation" (ie add a double quote if the line contains an uneven number of double quotes) or just to add a double quote any time the line does not end with a double quote?

Comment: @laurenOlga capture defines the area of a string / line that is being matched by the regex. The regex `(\d*)` would capture any Number in a String as a whole. I have a document with a lot of lines that contain a quote somewhere in the middle that is being followed by a bunch characters and I need to close every line that contains a quote with a quote. Since I don't currently have access to replace patterns I can only try to capture the gap between the last character of each line and ´\n´ or ´$´ and try to replace it with a quote. Lines with more than one quote in the middle do not occur.

Comment: From the information you give if you can't use regex from the command line to iterate over your file for whatever reason I agree with @Bohemian below - download notepad++ for free - it has built in find and replace including support for regex patterns such as \n - also it might help people to give you solutions if you define what you mean by not having access to replace patterns. Is it the program you're using or permissions related to the file itself that prevent you from using replace patterns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regular expression will find (and replace) only lines which have an odd number of `"`'s in them:

```
search_pattern = "(?m)^[^\"\n\r]*\"[^\"\n\r]*(?:\"[^\"\n\r]*\"[^\"\n\r]*)*$";
replace_pattern = "$0\"";
the_string.replaceAll(search_pattern, replace_pattern);
```

The important parts are:

- `(?m)` Count `^`/`$` as the beginning/end of *lines* instead of the whole string.
- `[^\"\n\r]*` Series of non-`"` and non-newline characters.
- `(?:\"[^\"\n\r]*\"[^\"\n\r]*)` Sequence of exactly two `"` characters, along with any number of non-`"` and non-newline characters. (The `*` afterword allows for any number of `"` pairs.)

If you're on Linux or have sed installed, you can also call this from the terminal or shell:

```
sed -r 's/^[^"\n\r]*"[^"\n\r]*("[^"\n\r]*"[^"\n\r]*)*$/\0"/' the_file.txt
```

Comment: This would work if I had access to replace patterns. Sadly I don't. Also I went through the approx. 1.2k lines manually in the meantime.
Thank you for your Answer though.

Comment: Accepted for being the most accurate Answer, even going beyond the scope of the actual problem. Bear in mind that it does not completely solve the problem though.

Answer (score 0):

To insert missing double quotes using something like notepad++ or sublime:

```
Find: (?m)^".*[^"]$
Replace: \0"
```

Note the absence of groups - the entire match is put back.

Comment: My Text editor does not support replacement regex. I could of course write a java Program to do the job, but since I have already finished doing it manually I am just trying to find a solution out of curiosity.

Comment: Download and use (the free) notepad++ or Sublime and your life will be easier

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't understand what do you mean by `end of line` but here is a working regex that **captures the line which contains a double quote but not at the end**: `^.*(?:").*[^"]$`

You can try this here: http://rubular.com/r/ppKo7E3qDP